# Stuck with interactive openGL program

Tags: c, opengl, shapes

I am having a crash everytime i try to enter two vertices with the mouse. I recently changed the way I organized each shape in order to make sure newer shapes were overlapping old ones.

The idea of this project is to make an interactive canvas of sorts. user can select between lines, triangles, and rectangles, then colors and a few more features.

I know the code for lines and triangles work, rectangles should work but I cant test it due to the crashes.

I think my issue is occurring n the left mouse button release area. And specifically with adding the shape id's to each structure in the "StructArray" array. Im sure its just something im overlooking.

Also an added note, my class is using the old openGL, so whatever openGL code that is already in the program needs to stay and I cant use the new stuff or shader based stuff.

If you need any clarification let me know.

I have included the C file aswell as the header files (UPDATE V2):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>

#include "lineseg.h"
#include "triseg.h"
#include "rectseg.h"
#include "colors.h"

#define MAXLINES 100

typedef struct shapes{
    int id;
} shapes;

enum {LINE, TRIANGLE, RECTANGLE};

shapes *ShapeArray[MAXLINES];


int currentcolor = BLACK;
GLfloat drawingcolor[][3] = {{0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}};
char *colorword[] = {"black", "red", "green", "blue"};

int shapenum = 0; // Number of shapes drawn
int linenum = 0;

Ln *LineSegments[MAXLINES]; // LineSegments is an array of pointers to Ln
Tri *TriangleSegments[MAXLINES]; // TriangleSegments is an array of pointers to Tri
Rect *RectangleSegments[MAXLINES]; // RectangelSegments is an array of pointers to Rect

int NumVertex = 2;

GLint currentx, currenty; // Used to store cursor coordinates
GLdouble dx, dy; // Passed to GetCursorPos, which needs pointers to doubles
GLint winwidth = 700, winheight = 700; // Window width and height
V2d *firstvert = NULL, *secondvert = NULL, *thirdvert = NULL, *fourthvert = NULL; // Pointers to vertices currently being drawn

V2d *make_vertex(int x, int y) {
    V2d *tmp;

    tmp = (V2d *) malloc(sizeof(V2d));
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("Out of memory\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    tmp->x = x;
    tmp->y = y;

    return tmp;
}

Ln *make_line(V2d v1, V2d v2) {
    Ln *tmp;

    tmp = (Ln *) malloc(sizeof(Ln));
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("Out of memory\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    tmp->v1 = v1;
    tmp->v2 = v2;

    return tmp;
}
Tri *make_triangle(V2d v1, V2d v2, V2d v3){
    Tri *tmp;

    tmp = (Tri *) malloc(sizeof(Tri));
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("Out of memory\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    tmp->v1 = v1;
    tmp->v2 = v2;
    tmp->v3 = v3;

    return tmp;
}

Rect *make_rectangle(V2d v1, V2d v2){
    Rect *tmp;

    tmp = (Rect *) malloc(sizeof(Rect));
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("Out of memory\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    tmp->v1 = v1;
    tmp->v2 = v2;

    return tmp;
}

void myInit(void)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, winwidth, winheight);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, winwidth, 0.0, winheight);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glPointSize(5.0);  // size used when rendering points
    glLineWidth(2.0);  // width used when rendering lines
    glLineStipple(2, 0xAAAA); // stippling pattern used when drawing a dotted line

    printf("Drawing in %s\n", colorword[currentcolor]);

}

void draw(void){

    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    for (int i = 0; i < shapenum; i++){
        if (ShapeArray[i]->id == LINE) {
            // Draw all lines that are already drawn and stored in the array LineSegments
            glColor3fv(drawingcolor[LineSegments[i]->color]);
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex2i(LineSegments[i]->v1.x, LineSegments[i]->v1.y);
            glVertex2i(LineSegments[i]->v2.x, LineSegments[i]->v2.y);
            glEnd();

            // Draw the segment that is currently being drawn
            if (firstvert != NULL) {
                glColor3fv(drawingcolor[currentcolor]);
                glBegin(GL_POINTS);
                glVertex2i(firstvert->x, firstvert->y);
                glEnd();
            }

            if (secondvert != NULL) {
                glColor3fv(drawingcolor[currentcolor]);
                glBegin(GL_POINTS);
                glVertex2i(secondvert->x, secondvert->y);
                glEnd();
                glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
                glBegin(GL_LINES);
                glVertex2i(firstvert->x, firstvert->y);
                glVertex2i(secondvert->x, secondvert->y);
                glEnd();
                glDisable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
            }
        }
        else if (ShapeArray[i]->id == TRIANGLE){
            glColor3fv(drawingcolor[TriangleSegments[i]->color]);
            glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
            glVertex2i(TriangleSegments[i]->v1.x, TriangleSegments[i]->v1.y);
            glVertex2i(TriangleSegments[i]->v2.x, TriangleSegments[i]->v2.y);
            glVertex2i(TriangleSegments[i]->v3.x, TriangleSegments[i]->v3.y);
            glEnd();

            if (firstvert != NULL) {
                glColor3fv(drawingcolor[currentcolor]);
                glBegin(GL_POINTS);
                glVertex2i(firstvert->x, firstvert->y);
                glEnd();
            }

            if (secondvert != NULL) {
                glColor3fv(drawingcolor[currentcolor]);
                glBegin(GL_POINTS);
                glVertex2i(secondvert->x, secondvert->y);
                glEnd();
                glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
                glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
                glVertex2i(firstvert->x, firstvert->y);
                glVertex2i(secondvert->x, secondvert->y);
                glVertex2i(thirdvert->x, thirdvert->y);
                glEnd();
                glDisable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
            }
        }
        else if (ShapeArray[i]->id == RECTANGLE){
            glColor3fv(drawingcolor[RectangleSegments[i]->color]);
            glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
            glVertex2i(RectangleSegments[i]->v1.x, RectangleSegments[i]->v1.y);
            glVertex2i(RectangleSegments[i]->v2.x, RectangleSegments[i]->v1.y);
            glVertex2i(RectangleSegments[i]->v2.x, RectangleSegments[i]->v2.y);
            glVertex2i(RectangleSegments[i]->v1.x, RectangleSegments[i]->v2.y);
            glEnd();

            if (firstvert != NULL) {
                glColor3fv(drawingcolor[currentcolor]);
                glBegin(GL_POINTS);
                glVertex2i(firstvert->x, firstvert->y);
                glEnd();
            }

            if (secondvert != NULL) {
                glColor3fv(drawingcolor[currentcolor]);
                glBegin(GL_POINTS);
                glVertex2i(secondvert->x, secondvert->y);
                glEnd();
                glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
                glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
                glVertex2i(firstvert->x, firstvert->y);
                glVertex2i(secondvert->x, secondvert->y);
                glEnd();
                glDisable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
            }
        }
    }
}

void keyboard(GLFWwindow *w, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
        switch (key) {
            case GLFW_KEY_R:
                currentcolor = (currentcolor != RED)?RED:BLACK;
                printf("Now drawing in %s\n", colorword[currentcolor]);
                break;
            case GLFW_KEY_G:
                currentcolor = (currentcolor != GREEN)?GREEN:BLACK;
                printf("Now drawing in %s\n", colorword[currentcolor]);
                break;
            case GLFW_KEY_B:
                currentcolor = (currentcolor != BLUE)?BLUE:BLACK;
                printf("Now drawing in %s\n", colorword[currentcolor]);
                break;
            case GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE:
            case GLFW_KEY_Q:
                printf("Exiting Program!\n");
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(w, GL_TRUE);
                break;
            case GLFW_KEY_C:
                printf("Now clearing window!\n");
                shapenum = 0; //clear shapes
                for (int i = 0; i < MAXLINES; i++){
                    free(ShapeArray[i]);
                }
                break;
            case GLFW_KEY_F:
                printf("Fill mode selected\n");

                break;
            case GLFW_KEY_F1:
                printf("Line mode selected\n");
                NumVertex = 2; //Line mode
                break;
            case GLFW_KEY_F2:
                printf("Triangle mode selected\n");
                NumVertex = 3; //Triangle mode
                break;
            case GLFW_KEY_F3:
                printf("Rectangle mode selected\n");
                NumVertex = 4; //rectangle mode
                break;
        }
}

// Cursor motion callback. Used only when mousebutton is pressed
// for first vertex and not released

void cursor(GLFWwindow *w, GLdouble cursorx, GLdouble cursory) {
    /* As the mouse moves, the second vertex is updated constantly. */
    /* Free old copies of secondvert before updating */

    currentx = (GLint)cursorx;
    currenty = (GLint)cursory;

    free(secondvert);
    secondvert = make_vertex(currentx, winheight - currenty);
}

// Mouse button callback

void mouse(GLFWwindow *w, int button, int action, int mods) {
    if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT) {
        if (action == GLFW_PRESS) {
            printf("%d\n",shapenum);
            glfwGetCursorPos(w, &dx, &dy);
            currentx = (GLint)dx;
            currenty = (GLint)dy;
            if (NumVertex == 2){
                if (firstvert == NULL) {/* save first vertex and register cursor motion callback for rubberbanding effect */
                    firstvert = make_vertex(currentx, winheight - currenty);
                    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(w, cursor);  // Set cursor motion callback
                }

                else /* save second vertex of segment */
                    secondvert = make_vertex(currentx, winheight - currenty);
            }

            else if (NumVertex == 3){
                if (firstvert == NULL) {/* save first vertex and register cursor motion callback for rubberbanding effect */
                    firstvert = make_vertex(currentx, winheight - currenty);
                    //glfwSetCursorPosCallback(w, cursor);  // Set cursor motion callback
                }

                else if (secondvert == NULL){/* save second vertex of segment */
                    secondvert = make_vertex(currentx, winheight - currenty);
                    //glfwSetCursorPosCallback(w, cursor);
                }

                else if (thirdvert == NULL){
                    thirdvert = make_vertex(currentx, winheight - currenty);
                    //glfwSetCursorPosCallback(w, cursor);
                }
            }
            else if (NumVertex == 4){
                if (firstvert == NULL) {/* save first vertex and register cursor motion callback for rubberbanding effect */
                    firstvert = make_vertex(currentx, winheight - currenty);
                    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(w, cursor);  // Set cursor motion callback
                }

                else{/* save second vertex of segment */
                    secondvert = make_vertex(currentx, winheight - currenty);
                }
            }

        } /* end mouse press action */

        else { // -----------------------------------------------NEED TO WORK OUT-----------------
            if (action == GLFW_RELEASE) {
                glfwSetCursorPosCallback(w, NULL); /* When button is released, disable cursor motion callback */
                if (NumVertex == 2){
                    if (secondvert != NULL) {
                        /* create a new line and put it in array (if size not exceeded). Set its color and id */
                        if (shapenum < MAXLINES) {
                            LineSegments[shapenum] = make_line(*firstvert, *secondvert);
                            LineSegments[shapenum]->color = currentcolor;
                            LineSegments[shapenum]->id = shapenum;
                            ShapeArray[shapenum]->id = LINE;
                            shapenum++;
                            firstvert = NULL;
                            secondvert = NULL;
                        }
                        else
                            printf("Maximum of %d reached. Cannot draw any more lines.\n", MAXLINES);
                    }
                }
                else if (NumVertex == 3){
                    if (thirdvert != NULL) {
                        if (shapenum < MAXLINES) {
                            TriangleSegments[shapenum] = make_triangle(*firstvert, *secondvert, *thirdvert);
                            TriangleSegments[shapenum]->color = currentcolor;
                            TriangleSegments[shapenum]->id = shapenum;
                            ShapeArray[shapenum]->id = TRIANGLE;
                            shapenum++;
                            firstvert = NULL;
                            secondvert = NULL;
                            thirdvert = NULL;
                        }
                        else
                            printf("Maximum of %d reached. Cannot draw any more lines.\n", MAXLINES);
                    }
                }
                else if (NumVertex == 4){
                    if (secondvert != NULL) {
                        if (shapenum < MAXLINES) {
                            RectangleSegments[shapenum] = make_rectangle(*firstvert, *secondvert);
                            RectangleSegments[shapenum]->color = currentcolor;
                            RectangleSegments[shapenum]->id = shapenum;
                            ShapeArray[shapenum]->id = RECTANGLE;
                            shapenum++;
                            firstvert = NULL;
                            secondvert = NULL;
                        }
                        else
                            printf("Maximum of %d reached. Cannot draw any more lines.\n", MAXLINES);
                    }
                }
            }
        } /* end mouse release action */
    } /* end left mouse click action */
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    GLFWwindow* window;
    const GLubyte* renderer;
    const GLubyte* version;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(winwidth, winheight, "HW_1", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXLINES; i++){
        ShapeArray[i] = malloc(sizeof *ShapeArray[i]);

    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* get version info */
    renderer = glGetString (GL_RENDERER); /* get renderer string */
    version = glGetString (GL_VERSION); /* version as a string */
    printf ("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
    printf ("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);

    myInit();
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyboard);     /* Callback functions */
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouse);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        draw();

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

triseg.h

```
// struct for triangle segments
typedef struct triangle {
    V2d v1;
    V2d v2;
    V2d v3;
    int color;
    int id;
} Tri;

Tri *make_triangle(V2d v1, V2d v2, V2d v3);
```

colors.h

```
enum {BLACK, RED, GREEN, BLUE};
```

rectseg.h

```
// struct for rectangle segments
typedef struct rectangle {
    V2d v1;
    V2d v2;
    V2d v3;
    V2d v4;
    int color;
    int id;
} Rect;

Rect *make_rectangle(V2d v1, V2d v2, V2d v3, V2d v4);
```

lineseg.h

```
// struct for two dimensional vertex
typedef struct vertex2d {
    int x;
    int y;
} V2d;

// struct for line segments
typedef struct line {
    V2d v1;
    V2d v2;
    int color;
    int id;
} Ln;

V2d *make_vertex(int x, int y);
Ln *make_line(V2d v1, V2d v2);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what am I doing wrong? I cant find where my issue is.

Comment: just need some guidance on where my code is breaking.

Comment: A debugger might be able to help you find out why your program crashes.

Comment: Okay, so what I have found is that the first mouse click and lift, records the vertex as it should, the second time it does aswell, but no information is being added into the ShapeArray. I updated the section of code on the OP.

Comment: Not clear from your post, where the code is crashing. Trying to guess though. What does `free(secondvert);` do in the function `cursor`? Assuming it frees the memory on heap, dont we need to check if `secondvert` is a valid pointer?

Comment: appreciate the help and sorry if i sound lost. That block of code was provided to me. It is there to track the cursor when the mouse is held after the first vertex. Im honestly not sure why its there, but before I created the shapes structure and added the for loop to check for what type of shape we were on, I didnt have a problem with it.

Answer (score 2):

You create the `ShapeArray` as an array of pointers,

```
shapes *ShapeArray[MAXLINES];
```

but I don't see any code where you actually malloc memory for the `shapes` within the array.  So when you do this:

```
ShapeArray[shapenum]->id = LINE;
```

I suspect you're accessing through a `NULL` pointer.

Maybe you should declare `ShapeArray` like this:

```
shapes ShapeArray[MAXLINES];
```

Then access like this:

```
ShapeArray[shapenum].id = LINE;
```

Or just malloc space for the `shapes` somewhere.

I also notice that your `draw` function seems a little confused.  You currently use `i` as a loop iterator within two nested loops, which is not going to do what you expect.

I think the inner loop is not required, so if we just look at the head of the function you should be doing something more like:

```
void draw(void){
  // Clear screen ahead of drawing all shapes
  glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  // Loop over each shape.
  for (int i = 0; i < shapenum; i++){
    // Is THIS shape a LINE?
    if (ShapeArray[i]->id == LINE) {
      // It is! Lets draw ONE line shape.
      glColor3fv(drawingcolor[LineSegments[i]->color]);
      glBegin(GL_LINES);
      glVertex2i(LineSegments[i]->v1.x, LineSegments[i]->v1.y);
      glVertex2i(LineSegments[i]->v2.x, LineSegments[i]->v2.y);
      glEnd();
    }

    // .... rest of function also needs fixing ...
```

Comment: so if i kept this `shapes *ShapeArray[MAXLINES];` and then added `for (int i = 0; i < MAXLINES; i++){
        ShapeArray[i] = malloc(sizeof *ShapeArray[i]);
        
    }` in the main, would i have created the space? not too experienced on malloc.

Comment: I knew there was some issue with the array! thanks! i can now draw lines again. Next issue im having. when I switch to the triangle mode using F2, I am able to click the first two vertices in and then the third crashes it. in the debug im also showing that it still has a NULL value at the time of the crash. any ideas? also updated the original code

Comment: @JoshFriedman I've extended the answer with some details of fixes needed to your `draw` function

Comment: your right! made the change, must have not seen it.I originally had three separate draw functions, and thought you could switch them around with the renderer. I have setup the draw function to place down a vertex as dots when clicked. on the first two vertices clicked, the dots dont show up. I have just traced how they are processed and the vertices are definitely stored as they should be, but I have no idea why the dots are not being drawn for the first shape. everything after shows them. There must be a condition in or something small that im missing.

Comment: Another thing, also just tested, rectangle and lines work perfectly, still having the issue with the dots showing up on the first shape, but atleast two features are working. I can draw one triangle and on the second, when i click to make the second vertex, it crashes.

Comment: Fixed the triangle issue: in the triangle section of draw(), under the second if statement where it is checking to see if the second vert is != NULL, there is a line under the `GL_LINE_LOOP` that is `glVertex2i(thirdvert->x, thirdvert->y);`, but since that bit of code is only connecting two vertices to make a line, there is no need for the third vertex. After it connects the two vertices, the user then clicks again and it outlines the triangle. Only issue I have now is the dots not showing up for the first shape of the program.

Comment: for some reason in the draw function, on the first shape, the GL_POINT begin sections are not being used and I have no idea why